# Is it possible to encode an arbitrary computation as a series of NP complete problem instances?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete

For example, can I make a compiler that transforms a C program (Turing complete language) into a bunch of SAT instances.

This encoding would be motivated as a way for specifying a problem piecemeal, where work on each piece could be verified in polynomial time.

Comment: Every problem in NP can be reduced to any NP-complete problem. That covers, for example, matrix multiplication, which is in P.

Comment: related [CNF generator for factoring](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16789/cnf-generator-for-factoring-problems)

Comment: a forward arithmetic operation can always be encoded in circuits. this is somewhat an EE exercise to understand that....

Comment: I have updated the example from 'Matrix multiplication' to 'a C program' to better express my question. I realise matrix multiplication/arithmetic may be encoded in combinatorial logic; but this seems like a more restricted problem class than 'any possible computation'? (sorry if my terminology is off here - it's been a long while since I've read CS theory!)

Comment: What do you mean by "encode"? What is the precise relationship between the original Turing machine (let's say that instead of "C program") and the sequence of SAT instances? Where does the Turing machine's input come into this?

Comment: Since there are arbitrarily hard problems beyond NP, you'd need arbitrarily many instances (*if* it works at all). I'd try to transform the semantics of basic operations into SAT instances, but that's probably hopeless without runtime data (the input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each program instance can be encoded as a (possibly very long; even infinite, if the program doesn't halt) series of NP complete problem instances, e.g. as follows:

For each "wire" inside a computer, we can derive a SAT formula that describes how the value (on or off) on this wire after the following clock signal depends on the currrent values of several other wires.  Using such SAT instances along with a set of variables that describe the current state of the computer, we are able to simulate any computation through a series of SAT instances.

Of course it is possible to combine multiple of these instances (or use a different approach), in order to simulate larger chunks of the computation at once. But there are limits:

If your original problem is in NP, then of course you can encode it as a single NP complete problem instance. But you probably will not gain much from doing this.

If your original problem is not in NP then you will need a superpolynomial number of NP complete problem instances in order to solve it, since a polynomial number of NP complete problem instances can be solved in polynomial time by an NDTM, implying that the problem is in NP.

So the short answer to your question is: "Yes, but usually not in a way that is helpful in the sense of your motivation."

Comment: If you don't have an a-priori bound on the running time of the Turing machine, you can't encode it as a SAT instance without "running" it. The especially problematic case is when the machine never halts.

Comment: @yuval I had the mindset of "If the machine halts, then there is a boundary and using this or any larger one leaves us with a valid SAT instance."  But yeah, if we want a general compiler, then this will not suffice and we need to be able to actually determine a boundary for the runtime, instead of just knowing about its existence.

Comment: @FrankW thanks, this approach makes sense. regarding unbounded runtime - from a practical perspective, it seems like we could still 'run' the program by compiling it to SAT instances 'just-in-time' (though it may never terminate).